# Python logging not showing up in gunicorn using gevent worker class

Tags: python, flask, logging, gunicorn, gevent

I have created a flask app whose main endpoint can be pinged to start a long-running function which may last up to a few hours.  When this endpoint is hit, I use flask-executor, which is a wrapper for ThreadPoolExecutor, to queue this long-running task.  This is the code for enqueing the task:
`executor.submit(start_crawl, id)`.

I do my flask setup in the root `__init__.py` file of my application, which looks like this (minimally, with routes that work defined as blueprints in another file and imported):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
executor = Executor(app)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(default_handler)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# https://trstringer.com/logging-flask-gunicorn-the-manageable-way/
if __name__ != '__main__':
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    app.logger.handlers.extend(gunicorn_logger.handlers)
    logger.handlers.extend(gunicorn_logger.handlers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

Next, throughout various parts of the code that runs during this long task, I use the following setup to log info:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("some info here")
```

When I run this code using the Flask development server, it works just fine and all log messages get displayed like I want them to.  However, when I run the server using gunicorn like this:
`nohup gunicorn -w 1 src:app -b 127.0.0.1:5000 --worker-class gevent > ./gunicorn_log.out 2> ./gunicorn_log.out & > /dev/null 2> /dev/null` I do not get any of my own log messages from the long-running code.  I have tried adding `--log-level info` and `--log-level INFO` to the gunicorn launch command but this has no effect.  Additionally, when I change the worker class to the default sync worker, the code logs as expected, so I think it may be some sort of gevent problem.  I think it's worth noting that the long-running function may spawn and log from additional threads, and also that logs from third-party libraries used in these threaded parts DO get picked up and logged to the gunicorn log file.  I have tried a bunch of different handler setups as well, like attaching more handlers or less to the logger I set up in init, but to no avail.  Has anyone had similar issues?

Comment: did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: @dada Nope, never did :(